# Batch File if process is running kill task

Tags: batch

I need to run this batch file remotely through PDQ deploy

here is the batch file:

```
@echo off
taskkill /f /im wccad.exe >nul
taskkill /f /im ACSR.exe >nul
cd C:\csg\wccad\
wccad.exe -run ACSR WIN_32
timeout 600 >nul
taskkill /f /im ACSR.exe >nul
```

Here is the ouput log after the job failed

> ERROR: The process "wccad.exe" not found. ERROR: Input redirection is
>   not supported, exiting the process immediately. ERROR: The process
>   "ACSR.exe" not found.

I think i need an if statement but i can't find any solutions on google people 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

[Redirect `STDERR` to `NUL` (hide errors)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) e.g. as `taskkill /f /im wccad.exe >nul 2>&1`:

Example (taken from an open `cmd` window via *copy&paste*):

```
==> taskkill /f /im wccad.exe >nul
ERROR: The process "wccad.exe" not found.

==> taskkill /f /im wccad.exe >nul 2>&1

==>
```

Comment: I am still receiving this error ERROR: Input redirection is not supported, exiting the process immediately.